# PostgreSQL query matching column text string extremely slow, even with index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table containing airline schedule data, which currently has about 450 million rows.

I cannot figure out why the below query on my database takes so long to run (several minutes). If I'm reading the query plan correctly, it seems to be getting hung up on one particular equality clause against a fully indexed column, so I'm not sure what else I can do to fix this.

Other queries don't seem to be running anywhere near as long, so it likely related to the query itself and not the hardware/other aspects. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The table in question:

```
   Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 pubdate     | date                        |           | not null |
 flowndate   | date                        |           | not null |
 carcode     | character varying(3)        |           | not null |
 fltno       | character varying(5)        |           | not null |
 acfttype    | character varying(4)        |           | not null |
 svctype     | character varying(5)        |           |          |
 traffrest   | character varying(1)        |           |          |
 depstn      | character varying(3)        |           | not null |
 arrstn      | character varying(3)        |           | not null |
 depdatetime | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 deputcvar   | smallint                    |           | not null |
 arrdatetime | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 arrutcvar   | smallint                    |           | not null |
 seats       | integer                     |           |          |
 acftclass   | character varying(3)        |           |          |
Indexes:
    "index_dailyflights_arrstn" btree (arrstn)
    "index_dailyflights_depstn" btree (depstn)
    "index_dailyflights_flowndate" btree (flowndate)
    "index_dailyflights_pubdate" btree (pubdate DESC)
```

The query:

```
SELECT carCode, COUNT(*) AS departures
FROM truesight_data.oag_dailyflights df
WHERE flowndate <@ '[2016-01-01,2017-10-31]'::daterange
AND (flowndate <= ((DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', pubDate) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date) OR PubDate = (SELECT MAX(PubDate) FROM truesight_data.oag_dailyflights))
AND depStn = 'PIT'
AND (svcType IN ('cargo','combi') OR acftClass = 'WB')
GROUP BY carCode
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

And the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of this query:

```
               QUERY PLAN                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=140256.14..140256.18 rows=18 width=11) (actual time=22013.297..22013.297 rows=2 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (count(*)) DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   Buffers: shared hit=985 read=142487
   I/O Timings: read=20089.741
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=140255.45..140255.76 rows=18 width=11) (actual time=22013.281..22013.284 rows=2 loops=1)
         Group Key: carcode
         Buffers: shared hit=985 read=142487
         I/O Timings: read=20089.741
         ->  Sort  (cost=140255.45..140255.49 rows=18 width=3) (actual time=22013.262..22013.263 rows=27 loops=1)
               Sort Key: carcode
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
               Buffers: shared hit=985 read=142487
               I/O Timings: read=20089.741
               ->  Index Scan using index_dailyflights_depstn on oag_dailyflights df  (cost=0.57..140255.07 rows=18 width=3) (actual time=13947.770..22013.193 rows=27 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((depstn)::text = 'PIT'::text)
                     Filter: ((flowndate <@ '[2016-01-01,2017-11-01)'::daterange) AND (((svctype)::text = ANY ('{cargo,combi}'::text[])) OR ((acftclass)::text = 'WB'::text)) AND current_status(df.*))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 616867
                     Buffers: shared hit=985 read=142487
                     I/O Timings: read=20089.741
 Planning Time: 0.460 ms
 Execution Time: 22013.389 ms
(22 rows)
```

Thanks again for any help--happy to answer any other questions you may have.

Comment: Can you please add the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Comment: Thanks--I updated the query plan above to show the full `explain (analyze, buffers)` output.

Comment: Postgres reads the index data with a speed of about 55 MB/second - this is on the lower range of a decent database server and that's limiting your query. What type of server/harddisk is that?

Comment: Your EXPLAIN plan does not match your query.  Where is current_status in your query? Where is PubDate in your plan?

Comment: You have lots of selectivity, but it isn't clear where it is coming from.  It would be nice to see how many rows are returned by each condition in your WHERE clause taken separately.  That could tell you what index to build.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is a regular index scan, which means it is reading both the index and the table in lock step.  Those two types of reads are not reported separately in the plan.  The table reads are probably mostly random, I don't think 55MB/second is bad for random reads.

Comment: @jjanes: but the query **is** pretty much limited by the I/O throughput. The only optimization would be to try going for an index only scan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I agree that the current execution plan is limited by I/O throughput.  But I don't think that that necessarily indicates a low-end server. I also don't think IOS is the only optimization.  There are lots of other options.  I wonder why this is not using a bitmap scan?

Comment: The execution plan doesn't seem to match the query. Where is the condition on `pubdate`?

Comment: The execution plan was copied and pasted directly...my guess is that since right now there are no records that currently fail this test (its for future-proofing) it just drops it entirely? Not sure how it knows this, though...

Answer (score 0):

You have a complicated `where` condition.  The only suggestion I can make is a compound index on `(depStn, flowndate)`.  This might help a bit depending on how selective the `flowndate` condition is.

Comment: I'll try this--I had previously created a compound index on `(flowndate, depstn)` that didn't help, but I know that the order does matter. It'll take a little while, though, to create the index.

Comment: It might need to be an GiST index, as the default btree does not support `<@`.  Although he could rewrite that into a BETWEEN instead.

Comment: @jjanes . . . Excellent point.  I was interpreting while reading ("oh this is a `between`) and missed that.

Comment: FWIW, I had originally used a `between` clause in an initial iteration, but was getting significantly better performance when I switched to using this structure, a date in a daterange -- an order of magnitude better (it was taking 10-12 minutes to run using a `between` clause, but only 1-2 minutes using the current structure).